# What k stores in that C program?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main () {
    int b[]={0,20,0,40,5};
    int i,*k;
    k=b;
    
}
```

***What pointer k stores?*** Is k store address of b or value of b????

Comment: As any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned, arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element. Which means that the assignment `k = b` is equal to `k = &b[0]`.

Comment: What if it's both since the *value* of `b` is a pointer to that array?

Comment: @tadman or what if it's neither? `k` stores the address of `b`'s first element.

Answer (score -1):

You could say that:

- `int *k = b;` stores the *value* of `b`;
- `int (*j)[] = &b;` stores the *address* of `b`.

However, except for being different types, the two represent the same memory address, `&b[0]`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int b[]={0,20,0,40,5};

    int *k = b;
    int (*j)[] = &b;

    if((void *)k == (void *)j)
        printf("b (%p) == &b (%p) == &b[0] (%p)\n", k, j, &b[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample [output](https://godbolt.org/z/qrP6z9):

```
b (0x7ffe1535a5d0) == &b (0x7ffe1535a5d0) == &b[0] (0x7ffe1535a5d0)
```

---

[ *EDIT* ]   To clarify the "*could say that*" and "*can be thought of as*" parts, neither means that `b[]` literally *is* an `int*`. It is certainly not, the variable `b` itself is an `int[]` array, as declared. But `b` *evaluates* to an `int*` pointer to the first element of the array whenever it is used in an expression, and in particular in the two cases most commonly associated with the notion of "*value*" in C.

- "***Value*** *assignment*" ([6.5.16/3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3)) "*stores a value in the object designated by the left operand*". For scalar types, this is simply a copy of the right-hand side value, for example `int v = 123; int o = v;`. For array types, however, the equivalent value assignment stores the value of the pointer to the beginning of the array, for example `int v[] = { 1, 2, 3}; int *o = v;`.
- "*Pass* ***by value***" when calling a function means ([6.5.2.2/4](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p4)) "*the arguments are evaluated, and each parameter is assigned the value of the corresponding argument*". The "*value*" of an array passed as an argument is, again, the pointer to the first element of the array, for example `int v[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; printf("%p\n", v);`.

The decay of arrays to pointers in (most) expressions follows from [6.3.2.1/3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3):

> *Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ''array of type'' is converted to an expression with type ''pointer to type'' that points to the initial element of the array object*

Comment: IMO, describing the address of the first element as "the value of `b`" is misleading as many people have an incorrect mental model of an array as a bipartite construct , consisting of a pointer and a memory block . You describe the value of that pointer, but there is in fact no such pointer.

Comment: @M.M Guess you suggest that the value of `b` is `{0,20,0,40,5}`, which is technically correct, of course, but also confusing in a different way. `b[]` is a "*value*" that decays to a pointer as soon as you try to use it as a value - assign it, pass it as an argument etc. In that sense, `int *k = b;` can be thought of as *the* value of `b`, instead.

Comment: Incorrectly describing `&b[0]` as the value of `b` fosters misunderstanding in students that causes them to make more mistakes in the future. Arrays are not pointers. The value of an array is not a pointer. There is no reason for this sloppy and wrong thinking or wording.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not mean (or write) that the value of an array *is* a pointer in the language-lawyer sense. Yet, an array reference decays to a pointer in many cases, and can be thought of as a pointer in the context of OP's question. I inserted an edit at the end of the answer to clarify that.